# Is it possible in 2020 to prevent DOM processing for Chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have use case when I don't want to allow for Chrom extensions to process my DOM because I have a huge DOM tree with a lot of events and any user extension has a dramatic influence on the speed of rendering and user interaction. Perhaps we have some attribute I can set on the body to prevent read DOM for any extension. I've spent some time searching but it was, unfortunately, haven't found the solution.

Comment: No, that would be silly.

Comment: yes... comment your whole code

Comment: Generally this is simply not your problem, if the user installs something that slows their page down, that's their choice and they're either willing to make the trade off, or they know their hardware can deal with it. (Perhaps consider optimising the huge DOM on your page instead, some dynamic loading/unloading content can go a long way)

Comment: @DBS DOM optimizing it's going to be the next step. But it would be nice to have some flag to prevent DOM parsing...

Comment: For a personal use case, you can use local Chrome policies to add a site to `runtime_blocked_hosts` of all extensions so they won't be able to inject their scripts into that site. It'll be fully invisible to them.